# Some answers don't allow comments. Why?

Tags: support, comments, new-users

I found a question similar to what I would ask. I wanted to add subquestion as before others did in grey (dimmed), but I didn't find a way.

In some questions I saw, that there is a posibility to "add comment". Why in some questions such posibility is possible and in some not?

---

UPD: [problems with UTF-8 encoding in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844286/problems-with-utf-8-encoding-in-php)

Comment: If you could post links to the questions it would help enormously.

Answer (score 5):

You [need 50 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to comment on questions (that you did *not* ask yourself) on Stack Overflow, but just 1 to do the same here at Meta. See also [How does the comment system and comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work)

Or, without any specific examples, maybe you're referring to migrated questions? Those (and other [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-question) questions) cannot be commented on.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for clarifying it. How could I gain reputation? Will I be correct if I assume, that by good answers to already opened question?

Comment: @Eugene, in a nutshell: yes. But for all gory details: see [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: @Eugene - the other, slower, way is to ask really good questions. Question up-votes are worth 5 points, while answer up-votes are worth 10.

Comment: Great. Thank you all very much. It is/was very educative discussion.

Comment: Commenting is not blocked for closed questions, even if you have not yet commented on them prior to closing. However, a locked question (which includes all migrated questions) cannot be commented on at all by normal users (don't know if diamonds get to bypass this like all the other things they can do to locked posts when necessary)

Comment: What should I do if there is already question with topic I need, but I can't comment on it? Should I leave comment as the answer or should I make a separate question?

Comment: @Eugene, unfortunately neither. So officially, if the question is really the same, in that case you'll really have to earn some reputation. After that, either comment or [set a bounty](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/) for that question to give it some attention. You've been a member on SO for two months now, no excuse for not having the 50 reputation required to comment... ;-) Accept an answer to your other question and get 2 points for free. (And maybe, as you're kind enough to ask: refer us to that question, to see if we can answer it after all?)

Comment: Fine ^_^. I have some questions up my sleeve.

Comment: @Eugene, see also the brand new [What can we do for new users who want to ask a question that’s already been asked, but hasn’t yet got an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54329/what-can-we-do-for-new-users-who-want-to-ask-a-question-thats-already-been-asked).