# What does "UPD" mean?

Tags: support

I see "UPD" all over Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange site and nowhere do I see it defined. Is it short for "update"?

An example:

`UPD: problems with UTF-8 encoding in PHP`

to be found at [Some answers don't allow comments. Why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53495/some-answers-dont-allow-comments-why)

Comment: Context is needed. UPD could be a short for update or could be a mistype of UDP. Both of those cases seem relatively common.

Comment: @ho1: Added link to an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means "update."  If you look at the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/53495/revisions) for the question you linked to you can see what was added.

Comment: I've personally never seen that except in the linked question (people normally say **Edit:**), but that does seem to be what was intended

Comment: @Michael: I usually write out "Update:" myself, but I think you're right, "Edit:" is probably a lot more common.  Without the link in the question, I thought "UPD" was a little ambiguous.

Comment: I found it all over the "cstheory" SE site and in a few place on meta SO.

Comment: @Michael: If you google **site:stackoverflow.com upd** you'll find a few instances where people write upd to mean update on the first pages of results.

Comment: Is this acronym used anywhere else? [See this comment on an answer that uses UPD](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/11212/problem-with-k-points-with-pw2wannier/11213#comment25677_11213). The user that wrote "UPD" in that answer has 0 un-deleted posts on SO or other SE sites apart from MMSE, so I wonder where they got the acronym. Furthermore, ***why not just write "update" instead of UPD?*** Does it save time for the OP or anyone reading it?