# When should locked questions be used?

Tags: discussion, locked-questions

The [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-question) currently contains very little detail on when we should suggest to a moderator that they lock a question. When should questions be locked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some examples of locking scenarios:

1. Popular questions that have many answers, which keep getting bumped to the front page because someone keeps adding an answer that already exists in the myriad of answers already posted.
2. Questions that get opened and closed repeatedly many times without achieving community consensus on whether they should stay open or closed.
3. Contentious questions that, for whatever reason, continue to attract flame posts.
4. In general, any question that appears to attract abuse, not otherwise handled by the automated checks and balances of the StackOverflow software.

Comment: Locked isn't really a good use for #1 at all; it's intended for #2 and #3

Comment: +1, I added #2 and #3 to the linked FAQ question.

Answer (score 0):

I know you linked to the page where this exists, but:

> Posts should generally only be locked
>   in cases of abuse. An example is that
>   repeated voting or editing is
>   happening in a way which games or
>   hacks the system.

Assuming you're looking for more color, can you clarify?

Comment: I think that Robert's answer makes it a bit clearer

Comment: @Casebash, agreed.  I'm up-voting his.