# When does a question get "locked"?

Tags: discussion, locked-questions

I remember seeing that some questions are locked. Meaning they are not closed, but you can't add additional answers.

When does this happens? Is it discussed here on meta, or is it left to moderators appreciation?

*I'm wondering about that because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624875/how-do-i-politely-decline-building-stuff-for-relatives-friends-closed) for which I understand people wanting to close it. But it would be a shame that it gets deleted since it's something any programmer (and other people working with computers) comes up with someday.*

Comment: see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post

Comment: WOW, what a crappy question that was that you linked to, I can't wait until it reopens so that I can close it.

Comment: You might also look at 'Protected' status, which this question may end up at also.  Remember close doesn't mean deleted (though it's then eligible for deletion).

Comment: @Lance Cases where the question shouldn't be reopened was the point of this question. Ok, I thought all closed questions get deleted at some stage.

Comment: No. Deletion is a separate function, and some classes are not intended to be closed. In particular, duplicate whose titles have markedly different words are to be kept *because* they can be found with a different search, and Joel has instituted a rule that requires very popular (many votes on questions and answers) posts to get *a lot* of votes before they are closed which appears intended to prevent that from happening.