# What's a locked question?

Tags: support, locked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “locked” post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)

Whats the difference between a locked question and closed question?

(I'm using the SO API and this appears for each question)

Comment: Please check out [What is a "locked" post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) To summarize, though, a Locked question prevents not only new answers like a Closed question, but also comments, votes, editing, and deletion. The latter points also apply to a Locked answer (as answers are capable of being locked).