# Can an answer of a closed question be accepted?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

If one of my questions were closed by somebody but I feel one of the answers were useful, can I still accept it?

Also, can any answer to a closed question be voted upon?

Comment: @Pop, I'll cast the final close vote, but wonder when the Team will figure out that Search is __really__ important.  Especially the related question search when you're typing in a question.

Comment: @Lance, okay...? Not sure why you're notifying me, I don't remember ever saying that search is unimportant.

Comment: @Pop, because you cast the first close vote, linking to a question that better searching might have found.  I also question the whole concept of closing as a duplicate of a FAQ question, but that's another issue.

Comment: kind of ironic...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you can still accept it, and answers can still be voted on by everyone. Other users can also vote on your question.

Only *[locking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)* prevents these actions.