# What is the deal with frequent re-tags, and how do we address it?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, locked-questions

I was reading this really old question [How do I move the turtle in LOGO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo) And noticed that it had 14 [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1003841/revisions). Some of them seem absolutely bizarre.

It seems like this was just a conflict of interest, but it got me thinking. I realize this kind of behavior doesn't happen often, but is there a way to stop it?

Can the original author lock his/her tags? Can a moderator?

Comment: Tag wars :) I guess lots of people disagreed about tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators can lock posts if there's an edit war going on.  We'll usually unlock it once both sides of the conflict have had a chance to cool down.  The question you linked to is currently locked, but there's not a lot more to say about it, so there's no real reason to unlock it.

Comment: Doesn't this affect all edits though, and not just tags? It seems like a strange thing to fight about...

Comment: Do moderators ever get into edit wars?

Comment: @diedthreetimes: Yes, it does affect all edits, and yes it is a strange thing to fight about.

Comment: @Siva: Not generally; that would be a really bad thing to do, as it undermines moderator authority.  I generally respect the other moderator's decisions, and rarely (if ever) override them.

Comment: @Siva: I was in an edit war once on a question I dare not link to (it doesn't need more attention), but that was before I was a moderator.

Answer (score 3):

That particular question is...how shall I say... [*special*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19500#19500). This doesn't normally happen, but if it does, moderators can [lock a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) to prevent edits. Use your flags to let them know this is needed.