# Why the answers are not locked, when any question is locked?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, locked, locked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “locked” post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)

When [any interesting Question or Post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you) is Locked, one can't vote for it.

But one can vote for It's answers.

Then user gets following notification.

[image]

Trying to up-vote question there will be ...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's based on lock.

- If moderator locks question, votes are locked for questions.
- If moderator locks answers, votes are locked from answers

Comment: What about this notification? It also tells truth **Question need votes too!**

Comment: @PiedPiper: but when it's closed, it's not possible. This behavior is really rare though

Comment: @PiedPiper that message is for *you* - it doesn't relate to the ***current*** question - it is merely noting that you have largely voted on answers recently