# Can anyone hack a question or an answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, locked

The answer to [What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) mentions:

```
A question where repeated voting or editing is happening in a way which 
games or hacks the system.
```

Is it possible for someone to hack a question or an answer?

If not what are the other reasons to `lock` a post?

Comment: That particular part of the answer was posted over three years ago so the SE codebase was possibly a little less..."refined" or something back then. In regard to editing/gaming it could be editing a question to bump it back to the front page, getting more views (and possibly votes). There was also one in regards to bounties and editing but I don't remember the details.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I might be wrong, but in that context I *suspect* it is referring to general abusive behaviour, rather than hack=tricking software. As in: mainly the "gaming". Keep in mind that the use of the word "hack" here was not by the SO team, and should not be interpreted as a security issue. The current "locked" messages are more along the lines of one of the following:

[image]