# This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved

Tags: support, moderators, locked-questions, post-notices

I posted an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919771/can-i-use-the-filesystem-api-for-a-chrome-extension-to-upload-an-image-to-a-fold), which did not satisfy the OP, hence his downvote.

After some comments, he [replaced his **own question** with bogus](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9919771/4) and walked through some of my recent answers [to cast some downvotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu6YK.png) (angry?). I undid this revision, which was repeatedly reverted.

Now, this question is [**locked**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post), with the following notice:

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info [visit meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

### Questions

1. How to track what's happening to the post? It's locked, so no comments can be added any more.
2. What does "disputes about its content are **being resolved**" imply?
   Ie, is any concrete action being taken (in the sense of "resolved by moderators"), or 
   does "resolved" refer to cooling down?

---

In a [comment below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127557/this-post-has-been-locked-while-disputes-about-its-content-are-being-resolved#comment346954_127558), Robert Harvey said that the notice shows the remaining lock time.
I do [not see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP38N.png) any time indication on the post. Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or should it be a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)?

Comment: Can anyone explain why "Too localised" votes are being cast on this question? The questions are generic, the example is only added for clarification.

Comment: You're right, they should really be voting to close as a duplicate of this question: [What is a "locked" post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228)

Comment: @TheEstablishment I've linked that question already. It indeed contains the answer to "What a locked post?", but not to the ones I mentioned.

Comment: I definitely think it answers number 2. Number 3 is either "too localized" or "already covered to death on Meta". If you don't think the linked question answers number 1, then we need to update the FAQ. It's community wiki, so feel free to do so yourself.

Comment: They're quite clear to me, so I don't know what answers you're looking for. If you wish to discuss the content, you visit the Meta site and discuss it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*I originally posted this as a comment, since it's just my best guesses/opinions, but Robert Harvey advised me to make it a full-fledged answer, so it's probably mostly on the mark.*

The "disputes about its content..." text is one of a few predefined messages available to mods at lock time. In this case, it's being used to mean "we're preventing the OP from trashing this post with useless text."

The system removes all serial "revenge" downvotes at the end of the day, no human intervention needed, so you don't need to submit flags or really do anything about the downvotes you received.

I don't expect this post to go anywhere productive. In my opinion, you should just move on and spend your valuable time where it'll be appreciated.

Comment: How are "Revenge votes" defined? AFAIK, it's hard for an automated system to distinguish three "useful downvotes" from three revenge votes.

Comment: @RobW - The system's algorithm is kept secret to prevent gaming, but it's usually very good (erring on the side of flagging too much rather than too little I think) and usually catches all cases. That said, if it doesn't get reversed within 24 hrs, flag a mod and they will look into it and make sure the problem gets resolved.

Answer (score 8):

The problems started with this revision:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9919771/4

Users are not allowed to redact content in this manner.  After that, a rollback war ensued.  The lock stops the rollback war.

Comment: So, this question is locked forever, and it's not looked after again?

Comment: The lock message says that there are 23 hours remaining in the lock.  The shortest amount of time a mod can lock is 1 hour.  The next shortest is 24 hours.

Comment: Not for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IP38N.png.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Non-moderators don't see this info. For all we know, it could be permanent.

Comment: The link above is broken. This is a another rollback-war link: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17519507/revisions (I don't have 2k here, and my edit is rejected.)

Answer (score 4):

The locking reason is one of the reason a moderator can select. Between the possible choices, that is the one that makes more sense, as it is generic enough.

[image: screenshot]

As Robert Harvey pointed out, the reason of the lock is the vandalism done from the OP on his own question. The lock would also avoid the user would delete his own question, which is I guess the reason the OP down-voted your answer (supposing it was really the OP who down-voted the answer).

Locks can be limited, and in this case the limit is set from the moderator when locking the question, or they can be unlimited; in this case, it is probable one of the moderators would check out to see if the question can be unlocked.

Comment: The second sentence of the second paragraph looks somewhat odd. Do you mean that the user is able to delete the question once all answers have one or fewer total upvotes? And yes, I'm certain that the OP downvoted the answer, since he stated it in a comment. Hence this [reply from another user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919771/can-i-use-the-filesystem-api-for-a-chrome-extension-to-upload-an-image-to-a-fold#comment12697912_9923841).

Comment: A question cannot be deleted if there are up-voted answers; I don't recall if there is a minimum required score, but for sure the question can be deleted if the existing answer's score is zero.