# Require Locks to reference a meta post

Tags: feature-request, moderation, locked

At the time of this writing, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093943/is-it-possible-to-make-a-div-50px-less-than-100-in-css3) is locked, with a comment sending people off to Meta SO, but not to any specific post.

This is rather annoying. IMHO locking a post should require/encourage linking to a meta discussion about this post.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that referring to a certain post would do any good. Given that this is one engine used on all sites, linking their against a post seems like a problem.

Comment: +1. It could *at least* link to [What is a locked post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) IMO.

Comment: The formulation is indeed confusing. I have seen people in the past coming over to Meta expecting there to be an ongoing discussion on the issue. Perhaps it can be reformulated to indicate that if a discussion about this is necessary, it should take place on Meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always understood the sentence as meaning:

- Visit meta to see if there is a question about the specific question.
- If there isn't any question on meta about that question, ask it.

To me, *visit meta* doesn't mean on meta there is surely the information I am looking for, but  it is the place where such information should be asked.

Probably, "For more info visit meta." could be removed, as users are supposed to know to ask on meta, in those cases. It still makes sense to use that sentence in the case it is an answer to be locked, to avoid users post comments to the question, asking why the answer has been locked.

Instead of *visit*, the sentence could use *consult*; IMO, it would be clearer the users are not just supposed to look at the meta site, but eventually ask a question, if they don't find any useful information in existing questions. (It is what I would expect users do, when they visit a meta site, and they don't find the information they were looking for.)

Comment: The wording "for more info" implies that there _is_ more info on Meta.

Comment: @lanzz: There is more info here, we've got a ton of questions about locked posts. If there is no directly related question to it, it can be asked. That's like linking "More Info Here" to the FAQ *and* the contact information.

Comment: Not if the previous sentence also implies that there are "ongoing disputes" _somewhere_. Which, it turns out is _not_ where people should be looking for more info? How does that make sense?

Comment: well at least they will be less inclined to ask the question on SO

Comment: @lanzz The meta site *is* the place where such information should be looked, and it is also the place where such information should be asked. If you have any question about a post you see in a Stack Exchange site, you should ask it in its meta site.

Comment: So, the point is that as long as the message is pointing in the right direction, it is OK to be as misleading as possible?

Comment: @lanzz To me, it is not misleading. The meta site is the place where to look for more information about locked posts, and it is also the place to ask for more information. The link is not for a completely unrelated site.

Comment: "while disputes about its content are being resolved" implies that are concrete disputes about this question. Where are those disputes if not on a specific Meta question? Should a Meta post disputing this question exist prior to its locking?

Comment: @ripper234 The dispute in this specific case is about the question being a duplicate; if you look at the question's [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11093943/revisions), the question has been closed, re-opened, re-closed, and re-opened. That is one of the reasons why a question is locked.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - but there are zero comments on the question ... I just don't get how a question can get so battled without any comments. Were comments deleted?

Comment: @ripper234 I personally avoid leaving such comments, which normally just generate debates. There could be no comments, and users vote to close the question, or re-open it. Disputes don't necessarily involve comments.