# No human activity allowed on a question

Tags: discussion, comments, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “locked” post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)

I came across [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) question, which is off the track, but I found it interesting.

Just want to know, why can't I upvote or comment on any of the answers. Is this any feature of SO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No more activity is allowed on that post because it is locked.

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

It was never a good, on-topic question for Stack Overflow, so it was migrated here to Meta to preserve it long ago.  It was subsequently locked because it still isn't a very good Meta question either.  It's just funny and that's about all it has going for it.

Comment: Hmm. Cool. Thanks. The post is really a historical piece to preserve ;)