# "Post Locked" should link to the meta FAQ on post locking

Tags: feature-request, locked-questions

I recently ran into [this locked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635678/openlayers-this-size-is-null?noredirect=1) and noticed the bottom part says:

[image: locked question]

It suggests I visit meta for more information. That does not seem very informative to me.

Suggestions:

1. The word **locked** should maybe link to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) here in meta.
2. `For more info visit meta` could be re-written to be more informative.

What do you suggest?

Comment: I agree with your solution #1. It's totally weird that you currently just fall on the MSO home page

Comment: I've always thought the `visit meta` link could point to the exact post that is discussing the content (if one exists).  The first time I clicked that link to see what the discussion was about, I was disappointed to find it just took me to the front page of MSO

Comment: Is there a discussion going on?

Comment: For the record: I locked this post because it was asked while the OP was in a fight in a certain chat room. I locked it to prevent the tension from there to affect the voting on the question. Although the question likely **is** *too localized*, the initial reaction felt a bit like ganging up/punishment.

Comment: @BackinaFlash In this specific case it was related to the JavaScript chat room. Gordon later explained that he locked the question because it was asked by a user who is generally disliked in the chat, and someone linked to it so he wanted to avoid bias. However, the solution I am looking for is more general. I'm using SO a lot for over a year now, I had no idea what locked questions were. What I ended up doing was going on google and searching for "StackOverflow locked question meta" and clicking the result.I would have appreciated having that in the question. I had no idea about locked posts.

Comment: @Jim I saw that question before posting this question. I'm asking for the bottom part added when locking to the mention what locking _is_. That question is about a discussion about why the question was locked to begin with.

Comment: Oh, I see. Didn't notice the difference. Not a duplicate. But closely related. Possibly could be one feature request to implement both changes.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, as I suspect that this message is placed when no more reason found, I think it could be better customized. Second, change the title of a link to the description of a locked post

> This post has been locked due to abuse of editing. [What is a *locked* post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)

> This post has been locked due to continuous closing and reopening. [What is a *locked* post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)

> This post has been locked because of attracting spam (or inappropriate answers). [What is a *locked* post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be a combination of nicael's answer and [psubee2003's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173624/post-locked-should-link-to-the-meta-faq-on-post-locking#comment516408_173624):

Whatever interface moderators use to lock questions should have the option to provide a link to a Meta post where the question is being discussed. The wording would change slightly:

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info, see: [< link to relevant meta post >](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)

If the moderator locking the question doesn't provide a link to a Meta post, the wording would be the same, but the link would point to the [What is a locked post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) question on MSO. This implementation would require a one-time change of wordiing, but from then on would just require a default link incluson when one isn't provided, so I think it would be simple for the SE team to implement (no new dialogs to write code for).