# Locked message should reference Help Center

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center, locked-questions, historical-lock

I noticed that the locked message still references the FAQ. See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books):

> ### locked by [Bill the Lizard♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) yesterday
>
> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/about).

Since the FAQ has been replaced by the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center), this message should provide a link there instead. Currently, the link actually takes you to the [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/about); even if it doesn't link to the help center, the text should probably be something like "More info: [About Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/about)".

Comment: In my opinion - It should not link to the first page of the help center or the FAQ at all, it should link [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) possibly. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173624/post-locked-should-link-to-the-meta-faq-on-post-locking

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, that's a good suggestion. But perhaps the Help Center should include a topic on the various statuses of posts, e.g. locked or protected in addition to on [hold / closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the source to use the help center link instead of the FAQ one.

However, with older posts, since we save the render HTML when the post is edited, it is unlikely to change.

Comment: Do you mean that lock messages are a type of post (like questions and answers)? If so they should be searchable through the Data Explorer, right?

Comment: @p.s.w.g - When a post is locked (historical lock) there is a post notice attached. Not sure if that gets surfaced in the Data Explorer though.

Comment: Ah okay so these notices are a separate entity in the database. That makes sense.