# Locked question banner still refers to FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, locked-questions

The message on locked questions still refers to the old FAQ (now the about page, but it referred to the FAQ before the introduction of the Help Center). It should refer to the relevant Meta question tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

Screen shot:

[image: Locked question banner references old FAQ]

Comment: I just noticed this question: [Locked message should reference Help Center](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193606/locked-message-should-reference-help-center). Would this be a duplicate?

Comment: Duplicate #4...and counting.