# A special kind of lock?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen, locked-questions

I've now noticed two closed questions that didn't have a reopen link:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174045/is-stack-overflow-killing-itself-by-parental-control

and

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174845/tired-of-serverfault-moderators

Is this a special kind of lock that moderators are putting on questions, or is it always that way when a mod does the final closing and I've just never noticed until now?

EDIT: The answers and comments cover it.  The first is a bug, the second I just missed.

Comment: Mods can apply a "full-post" (question and answers) lock, or a mere "question" lock. There's some backing verbiage [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229/130268), though can't say I really understand it.

Comment: Needs screenshot. And hand-drawn circles. With dropshadow. You must be new.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, yeh, but it doesn't note anywhere that there is a lock on it.

Comment: Here's another example of the "missing" lock notification: [stack overflow and asp.net forum?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176783/stack-overflow-and-asp-net-forum).  Almost asked this question until I found this question and @AnnaLear's mention of the bug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see the reopen link on both of them, but I'm not sure if that's a moderator thing.

The first one is silently locked because it was migrated and closing it rejected the migration. No changes to his "migration stub" are possible. The second one was locked explicitly by Shog and the lock will expire in a day or so.

In other words, this isn't a special lock. It's just a couple different cases of posts that happen to be closed *and* locked.

In the first case, there's also a bug - we only ever show two banners on a question, so "locked" gets lost because there's already "migrated from" and "closed as". I think a fix for that is in the plans. In the meantime, you can see that the question is locked by checking the revision history. (See [Seth's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174866/155160) for screenshots.)

Comment: It's special I guess in the sense that it's invisible to normal users.  I had no idea that the site had invisible locks.

Comment: @LanceRoberts You should be able to see the second one at least - the "locked" banner is right above the "closed as" banner. In the first case, it's a bug - we only ever show two banners on a question, so "locked" gets lost because there's already "migrated from" and "closed as". I think a fix for that is in the plans.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Seth beat me to taking screenshots. See his answer.

Comment: yep I just missed that one, I'll re-edit the question.

Comment: ok, if you edit in the bug part, I'll accept.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Done.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  They are locked.

The first one was locked by Shog:

[image]

The other by Community:

[image]

I know there are several types of locks, but I don't know what each does.