# Would like to vote but can't find a way

Tags: support, answers, voting

Sometimes I get a message to be sure to vote, but I can't seem to find a place to do it.  Some answers are just great, and I'd like to give them a positive rating.  Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: The buttons should be pretty obvious. Unless you somehow borked your css and made them hidden or something.

Comment: Some questions are [locked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post), and the voting interface is disabled on those questions. Other than that, you should be able to use the arrows to vote.

Answer (score 5):

You should see arrows around the post score (to the left over every post). You can see an example at https://stackoverflow.com/about.

If you don't see them, we'll need some extra information like your browser and operating system, and what posts you'd like to vote on. (As [Asad mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176080/would-like-to-vote-but-cant-find-a-way/176081#comment528386_176080), some are locked and voting is disabled on them.)

Comment: offtopic - thanks for getting rid of `http://hows.info` :D