# Is it possible to edit a locked answer?

Tags: support, locked

I did something stupid and posted a bit of an [answer including a placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16931434/31671) for something I was working on at the time.

I've since [completed](http://blog.alexanderdickson.com/javascript-nes-emulator-part-1) what I wanted to link to and decided to go back and edit the answer with the link, but it was locked before I could.

Normally I'd flag the answer for moderator attention (the [Locked Post FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post?rq=1) says this should be possible, hence the `bug` tag), but the only option I have left is to *share* my answer.

Is it possible I can edit my answer somehow, despite...

> This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed

?

Comment: Weird - this FAQ question says to flag the post (which doesn't seem to be possible): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post?rq=1

Comment: Normally, we should let historically locked posts rot. But I personally think this one is "good enough" to be maintained.

Comment: @Mysticial Thanks. I agree, and I realise it's my blunder, but I'd like to be given the chance to fix it.

Comment: You can still flag ordinary locked posts, just not a historically locked post. The historical lock is the final stage, and kind of implies the "we don't want to deal with this question anymore" so it makes sense not to allow flagging.

Comment: @animuson Do you agree the question should be locked?

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to be *that guy* but I don't think that your edit has it's place.

Like it says in the description, the whole purpose of locking this post is :

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: help center.

So the only reason why this question is being kept here it's for it's "nostalgia" value. If the question was simply off-topic and not locked, it would be deleted after some times and you wouldn't be allowed to edit your question. 
Allowing you to edit your question would go against the off-topic and the locking purpose. 
You see, if we would accept historical questions to be kept on the site without any restrictions, you would be allowed to edit it but the fact that we allow these questions to be kept here goes with the restriction that we cannot change the content of our answers no matter what.

Also, if people are really interested in knowing what is up with that emulator, they can naviguate your blog to find it, it's the first post in the feed.

> Is it possible to edit a locked answer?

No it is not possible. Not even by flagging. Simply because it would go against the purpose of locking the question.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. Though, I am not 100% agreed with why it was locked; the only thing I can think of is that it's a very broad question, but it was answered so concisely.

Comment: @alex It was locked because of the question's popularity when it was closed. But yes, I agree that closing this question was questionable in the first place.