# Why is my post locked?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, locked-questions

I posted this question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415261/how-to-get-the-threshold-of-pedometer-app-in-windows-phone

minitech♦ locked it afterwards with the comment:

> Hello. Rolling back to bump your post and try to get it answered will have the rather opposite effect of me preventing it from getting answered or being bumped. Thanks.

What's wrong with my post? How can I get it unlocked?

Comment: Who locked it? Do you have a link to the post? And, were there any other comments?

Comment: yes,i have  two link of image,cuz i very need 2 diagram to explain my question,but i have not enough reputation.And only this comment

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415261/how-to-get-the-threshold-of-pedometer-app-in-windows-phone

Answer (score 13):

You have been rolling that post back and forth between two basically-identical versions for a while. The only reason to do this is that you want to keep bumping your post over and over. Don't. This is considered abusive behaviour, so a moderator has locked the entire post to prevent you from doing it any more. This not only prevents you editing the question, but also prevents anyone from answering it. Hence the comment.

Comment: I did that because i am new here,and want to find what is Revision and why it becomes more when i choose another.

Comment: @user3072573 12 times though? Really?

Comment: I would like to upvote this answer and @JoshC comment but 12 is the magic number today...

Answer (score 11):

The lock message is pretty self explanatory.

It is because you were [rolling the question back multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20415261/revisions) consecutively in order to bring attention to the question. I consider this spam. The question was locked to prevent this.

[image]

Comment: Could u tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: You might want to start by owning up. And deciding to use proper spelling, punctuation, spacing and capitalization.

Comment: Do u mean i should post agian?

Comment: You should not, @user3072573. Just leave it be.

Comment: Will it be locked forever?If it will,no one can reply my post, how can i get my question solved?

Comment: I'd imagine that minitech, or another mod, will remove the lock at some point. Good object lesson, until then.

Comment: @user3072573: It's a 24 hour lock.

Answer (score 3):

Because you [rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20415261/revisions) the post 12 times and it's like switching between Revision 1 and 2.

From your comment

> I did that because i am new here,and want to find what is Revision and
>   why it becomes more when i choose another.

If you don't know about Revision check it on [Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

> What is a rollback?
>
> A rollback reverts a question or answer to a previous version in the
>   edit history. The rollback action itself then appears as the most
>   recent item in the edit history.

Comment: 1+.. I don't know why someone downvoted this..

Comment: @JoshC: Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @MidhunMP But how to make my post unlocked?Just leave it there?

Comment: @user3072573: If you disagree with the lock, you can flag that to moderator. (But I don't think in this case, it'll make any change). Please check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post

Comment: @JoshC Because Meta