# Undue attention to war-zone questions

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-reopen, bump

Sometimes a question becomes subject to a community war if it should be closed or left open, and goes back and forth between the two sides until a mod can come along to lock it pending meta discussion or what have you, as discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229/248652).

Until that happens, however, the question gets unusual attention, as it gets bumped to the top of the list each time it is reopened.

I think this is a problem for any situation, but particularly if the question is being disputed because one side feels it is inappropriate, the attention it gets as a result of the war is counter-intuitive to the subject of its closing.

Is it possible that after a question has been reopened multiple times, say twice, within a certain time frame, say an hour (or whatever is appropriate per site), that it no longer be bumped to the top when it is reopened?

Comment: Perhaps auto-locking and auto-flagging it is more appropriate. Devs: Can we get some data about how often questions would fit this criteria on the major sites?