# What is the severity of your question being locked?

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts, locked-questions

I know that when you post a lot of questions marked with duplicate, closed, and put on hold etc. you will be banned from asking.

So I guess there is a "bad question counter" to track your bad questions. And maybe labels such as duplicate and closed have different severities that adds different values to the counter. Something like this:

duplicate < on hold < closed < deleted

But where does locked go in this scale?

In the locked description, I saw that the question has historical importance but not necessarily good. So maybe it does not affect the bad question counter or does it?

Comment: [What is a "locked" post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It does not affect the 'bad' post count.

Post can be locked for several reasons. That the question wasn't closed means that the question at the time was on-topic. This doesn't mean it is on-topic now. Since it has value, even being off-topic, it can be locked.

Locking a post isn't bad. It is just a way to prevent future work on it. It also prevents others to use it as an excuse of posting off-topic questions.