# If the flag link is missing from a locked question, how do I flag it?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderator-tools, locked-questions

I would like a question to be unlocked for the following reasons

1. It was never voted by the community as being off-topic
2. It was therefore never closed.
3. There was no edit or flame war
4. It was so controversial it barely attracted any downvotes (/sarcasm)
5. it was never vandalised by the OP  or by anyone else
6. the visible answers are significantly different from one another
7. Because of its popularity, it did attract a large number of *on and off-topic* comments but these were moved to chat months before the question was actually locked.

Looking at the relevant meta post, [What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post),  it reads [emphasis in bold mine]

> ### What if I disagree with the lock applied to a post?
>
> If you have a justifiable reason that a post should be unlocked, **you should flag it for moderator attention** using the "flag" link underneath the post. Select the "other" flag reason, and provide a detailed explanation of your rationale in the textbox provided.
>
> A moderator will review your flag, and if they agree with your arguments, unlock the post.

There is no flag button/link. There is only a share link.

[image]

- Is this by design?
- Is this a bug?
- How can someone flag a locked post if there is no flag link?

Comment: In general, everything you can't flag directly, flag one of your own posts and link to what can't be flagged. Locking is used to stop flags as well, so I suspect it is by design.

Comment: @rene that sounds a bit contorted. The meta post should be made clearer.

Comment: Then edit it @Mari-LouA

Comment: Just to make sure, are you logged in? This looks like the view when we're not logged in.

Comment: Can you link the post so we can get some background on it?

Comment: I can flag this locked post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/578411 are there levels in locks that allow/disallow actions?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/395382/116151 I guess.

Comment: @PatrickHofman everything I have said is 100% accurate. You can see which year the question was posted. It was locked in January 2018.

Comment: @Glorfindel I'd prefer not to attract unnecessary attention

Comment: I didn't say it was accurate, there are just multiple factors with locks and we can't analyse them if we don't know the post.

Comment: @Mari-LouA well, luckily the post is locked so nothing can happen with the attention :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong FAQ. [This](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/395382/116151) is a post with a *historical lock*, which is different from a regular lock.

See [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/295232)

The [FAQ answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229/295232) you quoted starts with a warning about the difference:

> **Note:** The below answer only applies to posts locked for reasons other than "historical significance". The "historical significance" lock reason works differently.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: That was just a hunch, but I confirmed after checking the obvious suspects at https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsingle-word-requests%5D+locked%3A1

Comment: The "locked post" FAQ should include a link to the "historical lock post" Why are the two posts on different pages? Shouldn't they be merged?

Comment: Maybe (but that's another question...)