# Tell users what a "locked" post means on locked posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, locked-questions

When visiting a locked post you see:

[image]

I suggest adding a link to [What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) somewhere in there (e.g. making the word "locked" a link) so that users know what exactly this entails. Or maybe something like this:

[image]

Comment: That question you propose to link is a FAQ, and one *should* have read the FAQ if wondering what a X thing is on SE

Comment: @DarkCygnus Since it's a "Frequently Asked Question", what is the harm in giving the user an extra link to it in an appropriate place?

Comment: If it were up to me I'd put it :) just saying that FAQs aren't so hard to find as other posts when seeking answers

Comment: @DarkCygnus Very true. As Uphill Luge says, it's just a Google search away. However people may not know that, for example, stackoverflow belongs to the same network as stackexchange. I tend to like to make things easier for people instead of requiring them to use Google to find something basic and this would guarantee they're getting exactly the information they need in a single click and zero keystrokes away.