# Post locked by community

Tags: support, locked-questions

I had a post locked in psychology and neuroscience and I was wondering how to get it unlocked? I made some edits and it was also migrated from medical to psychology/neuroscience, so it probably has something to do with that. Is it a wait time thing and will automatically unlock? Or do I need to make a request to unlock it?

Comment: When a question is migrated to another site, the original question on the original site is automatically locked. You should make your edits on the destination question. See the relevant FAQ: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Also see: [What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)

Answer (score 3):

When a question is migrated it is locked.

This is the migrated post:

[Could this be a key insight in understanding the etiologies of neurodegenerative disorders?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/21684/could-this-be-a-key-insight-in-understanding-the-etiologies-of-neurodegenerative)

All edits should be made there.

If you look at the revision history of the migrated post:

https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/posts/18658/revisions

[image: history]

It was migrated then locked. All edits should be made to the new question.

## Unlocking the post

> If you have a justifiable reason that a post should be unlocked, you should flag it for moderator attention using the "flag" link underneath the post. Select the "other" flag reason, and provide a detailed explanation of your rationale in the textbox provided.
>
> A moderator will review your flag, and if they agree with your arguments, unlock the post.

Answer (score -1):

> If you have a justifiable reason that a post should be unlocked, you
>   should flag it for moderator attention using the "flag" link
>   underneath the post. Select the "other" flag reason, and provide a
>   detailed explanation of your rationale in the textbox provided.
>
> A moderator will review your flag, and if they agree with your
>   arguments, unlock the post.

Comment: What information does this answer add that [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324088/post-locked-by-community/324089#324089) does not have?

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle If you had looked through the [history of editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/324089/2), you would notice that the quote given in my answer was added later to another answer.